# How does Memory Corruption apply to Android?

Tags: exploit, mobile, android, java, memory

I have researched several DoS attacks within Android e.g.:

- CVE-2015-1474
- CVE-2013-5933
- CVE-2013-4710
- CVE-2012-6301
- etc.

And although I found DoS attacks within Android **difficult to understand at first**. Even though I understand what *Memory Corruption* is e.g:

- a programatic situation wherein, contents of memory locations are unintentionally modified due to programming errors: enabling attackers to execute arbitrary code etc.

As in the case of:

> Vulnerability Name: Microsoft Internet Explorer Memory Corruption Vulnerability
>
> Threat Type:  CWE-119: Buffer Errors
>
> IntelliShield ID: 37655
>
> CVE:  CVE-2015-1625

I **really can't understand** how the vulnerability memory corruption can be caused by Android code.

If someone could let me know. I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the Android applications are written in Java. As long as you don't use native code, it's not possible to cause buffer overflow or memory corruptions. In android it's possible to use native code and compile them using [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html). Applications like Firefox and Chrome are using native codes.

Many opensource libraries can be compiled for android e.g. [`libpng`](https://github.com/julienr/libpng-android). So a vulnerability in `libpng` for linux is also applicable for `libpng` in Android.